# Why does the column name "source" get rendered in grey in SSMS & VS T-SQL editor?

Tags: t-sql, ssms, pretty-print, visual-studio-2012

I have the following simple tSQL to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE NewsArticles
(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
lastCrawl DATETIME NULL,
snippet NVARCHAR(2083) NULL,
source NVARCHAR(2083) NULL,
title NVARCHAR(2083) NULL,
url NVARCHAR(2083) NULL)
```

In both Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio "source" is rendered in grey while the other column names are rendered green in SSMS or black in VS. Why? The word "source" does not appear to be a reserved word in [the list of SQL reserved keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.105))

[image]

Comment: This may seem an abstract unimportant question, but I'm getting errors when I try to insert rows from LINQ that have the source column set to null and during diagnosis I was struck by the different rendering.

Comment: It is a keyword used in `MERGE`. i.e. `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`

Comment: Perfect - I think that's an answer, thanks Martin. Do you want to move it from comment to answer and I'll mark it as such?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a keyword used in [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). i.e. `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`.

The word `MATCHED` also exhibits the same behaviour in that it gets highlighted grey in the editor.

Neither of these are [**reserved** keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) though so if used as an identifier they do not need to be delimited (unless you find the syntax highlighting distracting).

Comment: Follow up question; if you are using 'source' or 'matched' in a query, should you escape it somehow or enclose it in brackets?

Comment: @n00b, you do not need to escape "source". I have not tested "matched", however.